# How can I get SD Card label?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an app where I can delete files from the SD Card, and I also want to display the SD Card label, NOT the SD Card path, as there is a lot of informations on this already, but not that much about External Storage name.
When I'm talking about SD Card name, I mean the thing that is showed up when you mount it on a PC and in your file explorer it shows you the name of it like "John D SD Card"

Any help about that would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: If there’s a lot of information on getting the path then getting the name shouldn’t be that hard or am I missing something? Perhaps add your code for getting the path and explain why it doesn’t work?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry but I don't get it. How can I use the path to get the External Storage Name ? My SD Card is named "SD Alex" but the path I use to delete files from the app in my device is "/storage/sdcard1

Comment: That is what I wanted clarification about since you supplied so little information in your question and now I understand why this didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 7/N and up:

```
StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

List<StorageVolume> volumes = sm.getStorageVolumes();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int nr = -1;
while (++nr < volumes.size() )
    {
    StorageVolume volume = volumes.get(nr);
    
    sb.append(volume.getUuid()).append("\n");
    sb.append(volume.getState()).append("\n");
    //sb.append(volume.EXTRA_STORAGE_VOLUME + "\n");
    sb.append(volume.getDescription(context)).append("\n");
    sb.append(volume.toString()).append("\n");
    if ( VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            sb.append(volume.getDirectory()).append("\n");
    sb.append( "\n");
    }

        
Toast.makeText(context, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```